# MySQL query fails on integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, pdo

This query keeps failing with

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'login_name' cannot be null

My insert statement is...

```
    $insertUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO `users` (
                    `login_name`,
                    `password`, 
                    `first_name`,
                    `last_name`,
                    `company_name`,
                    `company_address`,
                    `country`,
                    `email`,
                    `phone_number`,
                    `agency_type`,
                    `sold_before`,
                    `authorised`,
                    `current_module`
                    )
                    VALUES (
                   :login_name, :login_password, :first_name, :last_name, :company_name, :company_address, :country, :email, :phone_number, :agency_type, :sold_before, 0, 0);';

    $bindings = array(':login_name'      => $loginName,
                      ':login_password'  => sha1($password . Config::PASSWORD_SALT),
                      ':first_name'      => $firstName,
                      ':last_name'       => $lastName,
                      ':company_name'    => $companyName,
                      ':company_address' => $companyAddress,
                      ':country'         => $country,
                      ':email'           => $emailAddress,
                      ':phone_number'     => $phone,
                      ':agency_type'     => null,
                      ':sold_before' => null  
                      );

print_r($bindings);                 

    Db::query($insertUserQuery, $bindings);
```

My database class can be found [at another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617646/is-this-wrapper-for-pdo-good-code-are-there-any-potential-problems). The `print_r()` tells me that the array definitely has a value.

May it have something to do with me using the word 'password' which is also a MySQL function?

Does PDO support prepared statements with INSERT in the same fashion as it does with SELECT?

Do I need to quote around the values, example ':login_name'?

Comment: are you sure $loginName is not null? 
have you tried debugging into the DB wrapper class? (though it seems ok)

Comment: Yes, I have echo'd all bindings data and it is coming out correctly.

Comment: Please try the following, instead of using the DB::query() function:

$statement = DB::getInstance()->prepare($insertUserQuery);
$statement->execute($bindings);

also, you may try removing the colons from the names in the bindings array for the execute()

Comment: @Itay Moav, the bindings happen in the static class.

Comment: the DB class is, i think, flawed - as it is using bindParam() instead of bindValue(). bindParam expects variables to be passed by reference - and it may be the culprit for some odd behaviour...

Comment: @jcinacio .. it worked when I used it like you described... can you post an answer and we'll discuss further? (if you'd like to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::query` doesn't support prepared statement syntax does it? Give [PDO::prepare](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) a read. You probably want something like:

```
$insertUserQuery = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`login_name`, ...) ' .
    'VALUES (:login_name, ...);';
$bindings = array(':login_name' => $loginName, ...);
$stmt = Db::prepare($insertUserQuery);
$stmt->execute($bindings);
```

You can also call `$stmt->bindValue()` instead of building an array of bindings. I think that explicitly binding each value is a little nicer since you can verify the types right there.

EDIT: sorry jcinacio, I didn't see that your comment was almost identical until after I posted.

Comment: I think I'm better off ditching my singleton pattern, as I'm putting more abstractions on PDO (which I guess abstracts away MySQL specific commands). Thanks for your answer.